# A way to get variable length integer or character

Tags: c++

I am looking for an easy way to get as input either a character or an int.
Easy way:
`k9asd8f0f`

```
a[0]=k
a[1]=9 //if its digit then '9'-'0'=9
a[2]=a
a[3]=s
...
```

But real big problem starts with:
`k90asd80f10k`
i would like it to be saved as:

```
a[0]=k
a[1]=90//!!
a[2]=a
a[3]=s
a[4]=d
a[5]=80//!!
…
```

So there is a big problem, i was trying to maybe get something like

```
int n;
cin>>n;
```

but this will zero my characters, and something like:

```
char n;
cin>>(int)n;
```

doesn't work.

I know i could search for the next variable so

```
while(1)
{
   int i=1;
   char n;
   cin>>n;
   if(n=='\n') break;
   while(n>='0' || n<= '9')
   {
      n=i*(n-'0');//this is only for double digits as char range doesn't allow more
      i*=10;
   }
   i=1
   cout << n;
}
```

but there i have problem with text pointer - for example if i have a10bdf, i will get an output a 10 d f (i will miss the first one after my double digit number)
Is there any fast/clear way to do it right?

Important: It doesn't have to be a char array, i would prefer int array and letters are 'names' to where input it:
I am trying to implement: example input: `52v230u24p42`, each letter have meaning like:

```
id->52
velocity->230
unions->24
points->42
```

If something is not understandable, I am sorry :)

Comment: You can use `cin.peek` to check if the next character is a digit. If it is then you can just read into an int since that will stop automatically when it encounters a non-digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    char c;
    int n;
    int test;
    test= scanf("%d", &n);
    if(!test)
        scanf("%c", &c);
    if(!test)
        cout << c;
    else
        cout << n;
```

that works great, but i still feel like wasting memory for either c or n and test(and is it susceptible for errors?), but if it is only way i think it is okay. If any of you would got a better solution, i would really appreciate this :) (maybe more cpp like?)
+ i have to use these 'ifs' everywhere

Comment: I am wasting memory as it will be recursive function for maybe 1000 ints and chars